# Angular Router Issue

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-universal

In Router am using some params in my router url, But actually if i add only params without any static data for more than one component, its not loading correctly. Below my code....

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path:'', redirectTo:"/", pathMatch:"full"},

  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },

  { path: 'aboutus', component: AboutusComponent },

  { path: ':cityname/property-sale', component: CityComponent },


  { path: ':cityname/:staticlocurl-:localityname-:localityid', component: localityComponent },


  { path: ':cityname/zone/:zonename-:zoneid', component: zoneComponent },

  { path: ':cityname/:proptypename-:proptypeid', component: typeComponent },

  { path: '**', redirectTo:"/" }
```

Inside this routers **localityComponent** and **typeComponent** complete path i set params without any static data like other router paths. So its not showing properly.

For **typecomponent** if i add like below it will work.

```
{ path: ':cityname/sale/:proptypename-:proptypeid', component: typeComponent },
```

Comment: if possible share stackblitz of your problem

Comment: Order matters there. Try moving the first 2 routes to the bottom, right before the route '**'

Comment: What do you mean by _not loading correctly_?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda check now i edited my question. Path am setting only params for two components.

Comment: @Arikael Check my question again. I edited now. Problem is i set only params for two components. is that possible..??

Comment: How does your path (url) looks like? And which component do you expect to render?

Comment: @John Both Components i have to render. with different contents. Url structure am trying to change without adding any static names...

Comment: why are static names not an option?
it would probably be the easiest and cleanest option

Comment: @Arikael Because of some SEO Prospective. Am trying to reduce Levels of URLs.